# tf Dataset does not seem to apply map

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I might be missing something very fundamental, but I have the following code:

```
train_dataset = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data_train[0:1], labels_train[0:1]))
                 .shuffle(500)
                 .batch(64)
                 .map(lambda x,y: (tf.cast(x, tf.float32), y))
                 .map(lambda x,y: (tf.image.random_flip_left_right(x), y))
                 .map(lambda x,y: (tf.image.random_contrast(x, 0.99, 0.999), y))
                 .map(lambda x,y: (tf.clip_by_value(x, 0., 255.)/255., y))
                 .prefetch(10))
for x,y in train_dataset.take(1):
    plt.imshow(x[0])
```

Why is it displaying always the same image? It seems that no preprocessing has been applied

Comment: You always see the same image because you only have one image. However, I see changes to your image, such as random flips, when I run your code a few times.

Comment: @AloneTogether yes, I mean that I want to see the same image with different transformations... however in my notebook the printed image is the same, with the same transformation...

Comment: @AloneTogether i think it has something to do with the fact that I'm running it on a notebook, because if I copy paste the code on a py file, it works fine